# Managing MySQL Database Table Development/Production Cycle

Tags: mysql, merge, development-environment

I would like to know what is the best practice to manage data of a website's MySQL table given the data is added to the table, both, on the live website and in parallel in the development phase, plus, during the development the structure of the table also changes.

A scenario could be as follow, let us have a MySQL InnoDB table with fields:

```
id, INT()
name, VARCHAR(255)
votes, INT()
```

The website goes live and table is constantly filled with data from the site. At the same time, the development team is working on the next version of the website and changes the structure of the table and also adds some data to it. Lets say the new table structure is now:

```
id, INT()
name, VARCHAR(255)
quality, DOUBLE()
```

In addition, remember, we also have to merge the two data sets from live website and the development version.

How do you do these kind of things?

Answer (score 0):

you can sync two databases using mysql workbench sync.

Also you can choose the direction for the updations

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-database-synchronization.html